# I am trying to update an array declared with useState, but I am getting the error 'Too many re-renders'

Tags: reactjs

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

setUsers([...users, { name: 'Alexandre'} ]);

console.log(users);
```

that's the only thing i'm trying to do. Please, help me

Comment: Can you show me the full code? Maybe it seems that you have to use useEffect() method.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to pass a function inside `setUsers`.
2. The function will provide you a `previous state` of the variable that you are trying to update.
3. Use that `previous state` to create a new state (array) and return it from the function.
4. The returned value will be updated in the state.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

setUsers((prevStateOfUsers) => {

 const newStateOfUsers = [...prevStateOfUsers, { name: 'Alexandre'} ];

 return newStateOfUsers; 

});

console.log(users);
```

[Link to official react js docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

One liner solution for oneliner-lovers

```
setUsers((prevStateOfUsers) => [...prevStateOfUsers, { name: 'Alexandre'} ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Example() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUsers([...users, { name: 'Alexandre'} ]);
    console.log(users);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      something...
    </div>
  );
}
```

Keyword is useEffect.

Comment: If it works, please vote my answer!! haha!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

can you put the code of page ? or you can write this code :

In function

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'; 

const Component = ({ setUsers }) => {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const addMember = (value) => {
    setUsers([...users, {      
      name: value,
    }]);
  };

  return (
    your code...
  );
};
```

Or as indicated by Artem Medianyk in useEffect

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

 const Component = () => {

  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setUsers([...users, {
       name: 'Alexandre',
    }]);
  }, []);

  return (
   your code...
  );
};
```